# Can you help me to find out the wrong words in the brackets? Thank you ^_^

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality

1.The factory (was closed down) (considering) the use of excessive (chemical) made the river (dries out)

2.The Maasai tribe (are) people (whom) have (wondered) throughout the world for (nearly) 1000 years

3.Del Piero (has become) one of the (greatest) fottballer that the world has (ever known)

4.By 1990, 1.5 (millions) people (were) living in an area that in 1960 (had) a population (of) 180.000

5.Nowadays many people (need) technology (because) (it) is important in (shape) modern lifestyle

Can you help me to find out the wrong words in the brackets? Thank you ^_^

Comment: What is the point of the parenthesis? Are they trying to show words that can be removed and keep the meaning or what?

Comment: I wanted to edit your question but indeed it is unclear what the words in the parentheses present. And for me, they don't seem wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but this site doesn't really work like this.  If you have a specific question about learning English, please ask it. However you can't copy your homework into a question and ask us to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your respons all... honestly, it is not homework ,If it is a homework :) i will do by myself. I ask these questions that because  I'm preparing myself for entrance an university and there's english test like toefl. because I just know a few about grammar (you can see in this sentences ,there are many mistakes :( ), But, before I ask in here , I have tried to work some questions. Sorry if I do something wrong :( i just wanna learn and understand english. Thank you ^_^

Comment: @BrendaZusriadi This question will be closed because it's not asking about one specific issue. You need to narrow it down.

Comment: Oh no problem , i will try to ask with specific issue . Thank you..